# linq returns DateTime hour in AM/PM format

Tags: linq, format

linq send hour part of DateTime to sql in AM/PM format.

```
q.Where(d => TD.ToList().Contains(d.dt.Hour));
```

How should I get hour in 24 hour format?

Comment: What is `q`? What is `TD`? What is `d`?

Comment: sorry for confusion. q is my IQueryable, TD is a list of ints (like 23, 13, 7, which are hours). d is the linq variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are using [`DateTime.Hour`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.hour%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) you always have hours in 24-hour format. MSDN:

> The value of the Hour property is always expressed using a 24-hour
>   clock. To retrieve a string that represents the hour of a date and
>   time using a 12-hour clock, call the DateTime.ToString(String) or
>   DateTime.ToString(String, IFormatProvider) method with the "h" custom
>   format specifier.

I.e. DateTime contains data, which can be formatted. But when you use Hours, they don't have any format. So, your problem is elsewhere. Probably you are storing incorrect values in database.

Comment: Thanks! You are right. I just checked my db for 2 periods which I did not have any data at those hours. I checked again and I found out that actually the linq query works correctly!